# A complete tool for auditing and archiving emails would be helpful for the community?

Tags: email, postfix

Please, don't treat this like a discussion question, I'm looking for direct answers: Yes / No, because...

I work on a financial company and I'm needing a tool for email archiving and auditing. The compliance sector is asking for it and I have to provide it.

I've searched and found two solutions: MailStore (commercial, Windows only) and Enkive (open source, very poor UI and lack of features). I'm using Postfix as MTA and Courier for IMAP/POP access.

I'm almost deciding to write it myself, I have the knowledge needed, but I'm wondering right now if it's worth to put (a lot) more hours to make it open source and user friendly.

So my question is, have you ever had the same need? Would this be a helpful solution? Is there any other good tool that I haven't found?

**Edit:** I'm running Postfix on a Debian box and need to archive and audit all the emails that passes through the server. The tools I mentioned above doesn't fit my needs so, in the last case, I'm willing to develop one myself. Do you know any mature tool that can help me? Or to develop one seems to be the best solution?

Thank you!

Comment: This is halfway between a survey question and a shopping question, with neither of those being on-topic.

Comment: I think there's an obvious failure to understand the core of what a good question is - Generally there's a problem, you look for a solution. Reformulating the question as "How would I archive and audit emails with this MTA and this mail server" then mentioning the issues with current solutions, and asking what someone would look for in choosing one might work better. Asking people to treat a polling question as a non polling question without the slightest attempt at sneakiness - well the question got downvoted didn't it?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Your reformulation is just perfect... I'm sorry for the original question, I'm new to SO/SF, I understand now why my question was downvoted. I was trying to achieve direct answers and I thought the question was pretty direct.

Answer (score 3):

I'm in 2 minds on this one...

**The IT Manager in me says**: If there's really nothing out there that suits your needs, even with some minor modifications, and the business will support you in writing *and maintaining* your own, then go for it. But really make sure there's nothing else out there that can do it for you. No sense reinventing the wheel if all you need is a different spoke pattern.

**The Open Source user in me says**: Do it!! As far as I'm aware, there's no reasonably complete project like this out there. I actually did have a brief play with making one myself for that reason, but gave up pretty quick since I don't actually need one myself at the present time.

Comment: Thank you! At least I know I'm not the only one who searched for a good solution and haven't found one.